# What is the difference between concurrent.futures and asyncio.futures?

Tags: python, python-3.x, module, python-asyncio, concurrent.futures

To clarify the reason for this question:

1. It is confusing to use two modules with the same name. What do they represent that makes them distinct?
2. What task(s) can one solve that the other can't and vice-versa?

Comment: For anyone needing to use `concurrent.futures Future` objects in code that uses `asyncio`, wrap the `Future` objects with [asyncio.wrap_future](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-future.html#asyncio.wrap_future), which makes them `awaitable`.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

The [`asyncio` documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#future) covers the differences:

> class `asyncio.Future(*, loop=None)`
>
> This class is almost compatible with `concurrent.futures.Future`.
>
> Differences:
>
> - `result()` and `exception()` do not take a timeout argument and raise an exception when the future isn’t done yet.
> - Callbacks registered with `add_done_callback()` are always called via the event loop’s `call_soon_threadsafe()`.
> - This class is not compatible with the `wait()` and `as_completed()` functions in the `concurrent.futures` package.
>
> This class is not thread safe.

Basically, if you're using `ThreadPoolExecutor` or `ProcessPoolExecutor`, or want to use a `Future` directly for thread-based or process-based concurrency, use `concurrent.futures.Future`. If you're using `asyncio`, use `asyncio.Future`.

Comment: So it isn't thread safe, unless you use  `add_done_callback()`?

Comment: `asyncio.Future` isn't thread-safe at all - it's only designed to be used in a single-threaded, `asyncio`-based application. If you want to call a method on `asyncio.Future` from a thread outside of the event loop thread, you'd need to use `loop.call_soon_threadsafe`.

Answer (score 4):

From the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio.html#module-asyncio):

> [`asyncio` provides a] Future class that mimics the one in the concurrent.futures module, but adapted for use with the event loop;

Comment: Does that mean they have duplicated functionality?

Comment: Yes; please refer to the docstring for `asyncio.futures.Future`.

Comment: Thanks, the more I read the docstrings, the clearer the difference gets.

Comment: I find that concurrent.futures is less of a hassle than asyncio