# Can concurrent.futures.Future be converted to asyncio.Future?

Tags: python-3.x, python-asyncio, python-multithreading, concurrent.futures

I'm practicing `asyncio` after writing multithreaded code many years.

Noticed something which i find it strange. Both in `asyncio` and in `concurrent` there is a `Future` object.

```
from asyncio import Future
from concurrent.futures import Future
```

Guess each onee has it's own role..

My question is if i can transfer `concurrent.future.Future` to `asyncio.Future` (or the opposite)?

Comment: Not sure if exactly a duplicate, but definitely related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29902908/what-is-the-difference-between-concurrent-futures-and-asyncio-futures

Comment: Thanks. read it, there is a comparisson there, no answer for me yet..

Comment: mkrieger1's post is helpful. I'm not sure what do you mean by transfer to the other

Answer (score 16, accepted):

> My question is if i can transfer `concurrent.future.Future` to `asyncio.Future` (or the opposite)?

If by "transfer" you mean convert one to the other, yes, it's possible, although bridging the impedance mismatch can take some work.

To convert a [`concurrent.futures.Future`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#concurrent.futures.Future) into an [`asyncio.Future`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-future.html#asyncio.Future), you can call `asyncio.wrap_future`. The returned asyncio future is awaitable in the asyncio event loop and will complete when the underlying threading future completes. This is effectively how [`run_in_executor`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#asyncio.loop.run_in_executor) is [implemented](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/feb0846c3a28b05b4cfbc6ab34c764957f3eff55/Lib/asyncio/base_events.py#L800).

There is no public functionality to directly convert an asyncio future to `concurrent.futures` future, but there is the [`asyncio.run_coroutine_threadsafe`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.run_coroutine_threadsafe) function, which takes a *coroutine*, submits it to an event loop, and returns a concurrent future which completes when the asyncio future does. This can be used to effectively convert any asyncio-awaitable future to concurrent future, like this:

```
def to_concurrent(fut, loop):
    async def wait():
        await fut
    return asyncio.run_coroutine_threadsafe(wait(), loop)
```

The returned future will behave like you'd expect from a concurrent future, e.g. its [`result()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#concurrent.futures.Future.result) method will block, etc. One thing you might want to be careful of is that callbacks added to the concurrent future with [`add_done_callback`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#concurrent.futures.Future.add_done_callback) run in the thread that marked the future completed, which in this case is the event loop thread. This means that if you add some done callbacks, you need to be careful not to invoke blocking calls in their implementation lest you block the event loop.

Note that calling `run_coroutine_threadsafe` requires the event loop to actually *run* in some other thread. (For example, you can start a background thread and have it execute `loop.run_forever`.)

Answer (score 3):

There is a function called `wrap_future` in asyncio.

> Wrap a concurrent.futures.Future object in a asyncio.Future object.

See https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-future.html#asyncio.wrap_future

Answer (score 2):

For the "concurrent future to asyncio future" part, here is an utility I use.

```
from typing import List, Any
from concurrent.futures.thread import ThreadPoolExecutor
import asyncio


class AsyncThreadPool(ThreadPoolExecutor):
    _futures: List[asyncio.Future]
    _loop: asyncio.AbstractEventLoop

    def __init__(self, max_workers=None):
        super().__init__(max_workers)
        self._futures = []

    def queue(self, fn):
        self._loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
        fut = self._loop.create_future()
        self._futures.append(fut)
        self.submit(self._entry, fn, fut)

    def queueAsync(self, coroutine):
        def newLoop():
            loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
            asyncio.set_event_loop(loop)
            return loop.run_until_complete(coroutine)
        self.queue(newLoop)

    def _entry(self, fn, fut: asyncio.Future):
        try:
            result = fn()
            self._loop.call_soon_threadsafe(fut.set_result, result)
        except Exception as e:
            self._loop.call_soon_threadsafe(fut.set_exception, e)

    async def gather(self) -> List[Any]:
        return await asyncio.gather(*self._futures)
```

You can use it like that:

```
with AsyncThreadPool() as pool:
    # Queue some sync function (will be executed on another thread)
    pool.queue(someHeavySyncFunction)
    # Queue a coroutine that will be executed on a new event loop running on another thread
    pool.queue(otherAsyncFunction())

    # Gather results (non blocking for your current loop)
    res: List[Any] = await pool.gather()
```

Comment: Since `AsyncPool` already runs inside an event loop, wouldn't it be more efficient for `queueAsync` to just call `self._futures.append(asyncio.create_task(coroutine))`? Creating multiple event loops is somewhat of an antipattern in asyncio.